# Nginx serves the wrong certificate. Two domains with redirect

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have two domains `example.com` and `example.org`. Both domains point to the same server with a static IP.

The first configuration file (for `example.com`):

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com.conf

# Catchall for all non-existent domains
server {
   return 404;
}

# Should redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# Should redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  # Using LetsEncrypt certs
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  root /var/www/example.com/;
  index index.html;

}
```

And here's the other configuration file

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.org.conf

# Should redirect http://example.org to https://example.org
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.org;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# Should redirect http://www.example.org to https://www.example.org
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.org;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.org;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;

  root /var/www/example.org/;
  index index.html;

}
```

So here's the problem

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com ✔
https://example.com ✔
http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com ✔
https://www.example.com ✔

http://example.org -> https://example.org ✔
https://example.org ✔
http://www.example.org -> https://www.example.org ✗
https://www.example.org ✗
```

In the last two cases (`www.example.org`) the certificate of `example.com` is served.

SNI support is enabled: `$ nginx -V  =>  TLS SNI support enabled`

What's wrong with my config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have `server_name`s for the secure versions of your domains when using the `www.` prefix, so the default server is used in each case.

In the absence of an explicit default server, the first server block matching the appropriate port is used.

You need to add the `www.` variants to the `server_name` directive in your secure `server` blocks, or use the wild card syntax.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredible fast answer! That solved the issue!

Comment: In my case, I need to `listen example.com:443 ssl;`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had edited my local `/etc/hosts` file to point the domain I was testing to a different server ip address which did not have that site enabled in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory. Nginx served out a different website instead, and thus a different certificate.